# What is the difference between Slavic little yus and little iotified yus?

Tags: slavic-languages

What is the difference between Old Slavic little yus ѧ and little iotified yus ѩ, and what does "iotation" mean in this context?

Relating to the difference between ѧ and ѩ, is the earliest form of the word "five" spelt пѧть or пѩть? If the earliest form is пѩть, why is this word written with ѩ while имѧ is written with ѧ?

Comment: Assuming the intent of the question asker, I've rewritten it to sound more like one question with two related parts, rather than a number of disjointed questions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the Old Church Slavonic language (OCS), the little yus Ѧ represented a nasalized front vowel, possibly [ɛ̃], and is traditionally transliterated as <ę>, while the little iotified yus Ѩ, as it is clearly seen from its name, is [j] + Ѧ, that is [jɛ̃], <ję> and is a ligature of I and Ѧ. The little iotified yus Ѩ was written in the beginning of words and after vowels where it was read as [jɛ̃] (e.g. ѩти [jɛ̃ti] “to take”, imperfective), or after consonants where it was read as [ɛ̃] together with showing that the previous consonant is palatal, but in this last case Ѧ was more typical, e.g. възѧти (vъzęti) [vŭzʲɛ̃ti] “to take”, perfective.

As for the OCS word for “five”, it was **пѧть** (pętь) [pɛ̃tĭ], [derived](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BF%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8C#Etymology_1) from the Proto-Indo-European **pénkʷe*. That word had neither [j] nor palatal [*pʲ] which didn't exist at all in OCS. That is why the spelling **пѩть** is highly divergent and weird, it can be explained either as a typo or as a highly idiosyncratic local and late variant. Even the modern Russian Church Slavonic [has it](https://azbyka.ru/biblia/?Gen.1&r%7Eutfcs%7Ea#sel=87:8,87:8) with Ѧ, cf. Genesis 1:23:

[image]

The little iotified yus Ѩ is *not typical* after consonants.

Comment: It is not a typo see also мѩсо плѩсати  памѩть тысѩшти

Comment: @fedor - You'd do a great favor for our community by providing links to the sources of you examples with Ѩ.

Comment: https://lexicography.online/etymology/vasmer/п/память https://lexicography.online/etymology/vasmer/п/плясать https://lexicography.online/etymology/vasmer/т/тысяча https://lexicography.online/etymology/vasmer/м/мясо https://lexicography.online/etymology/vasmer/п/пять

Comment: @fedor - [Here](https://imgur.com/Awc3KB3) is a screenshot from a scan of the _real paper_ Vasmer's _Etymological dictionary_, vol. 3, 1987, p. 30, the entry for _мясо_ where the OCS form is given as м**ѧ**со. [Here](https://imgur.com/FLhLVtQ) is a screenshot from the paper Vasmer's entry for _тысяча_, and again in fact it's **Ѧ** there, not Ѩ (vol. 4, 1987, p. 133). _Unfortunately, your source is not trustworthy._

Comment: @fedor - A [screenshot](https://imgur.com/LZeH45b) from the paper Vasmer's entry for _пять_, and again it's **пѧть** there, with **ѧ** (vol. 3, 1987, p. 426).

Comment: I know that Vasmer's dictionary has several editions

Comment: Here's a [screenshot](https://imgur.com/FXySiU4) from the original German language edition of Vasmer, 1955, vol. 2, p. 479, entry for _пять_. In this edition the OCS forms are transliterated, here we have _pętь_, again no _j_, no palatalisation of _p_. And in addition, a [screenshot](https://imgur.com/1jXRbNp) from Rick Derksen's _Etymological Dictionary of the Slavic Inherited Lexicon_, Brill Academic Pub., 2008, p. 400, again _pętь_. Haven't screenshots from so many dictionaries persuaded you yet? On your side there're just links to an obscure textual site.

Comment: @fedor - My last argument that those textual Vasmer sites have a mistake, Ѩ instead of Ѧ, which they copy from one another is [this site](https://vasmer.slovaronline.com/) which states its etymologies are taken from the 1986-1987 edition of Vasmer. You saw my screenshots from that edition on paper, it has Ѧ in those words. But see [what they say for _пять_](https://vasmer.slovaronline.com/10727-PYAT) — they have it as пѩть which is _not what the actual book has_. Maybe they have typesetting problems, I don't know, but there's no evidence of пѩть other than those sites.

Comment: Could you please give a link to https://imgur.com/FXySiU4?

Comment: @prostorech - Do you mean this? https://i.imgur.com/FXySiU4.jpg Do you have a problem accessing the image?

Comment: I want to see an original edition etymology of another word "цѣдити"

Comment: @prostorech - Here it is for "цѣдити": https://i.imgur.com/EfOfBl3.jpg . And [here's](https://www.mediafire.com/file/6lcm11js3725li7/Russisches_etymologisches_W%25C3%25B6rterbuch%252C_B%25C3%25A4nde_I-III_%255B1953-1958%252C_Max_Vasmer%255D.pdf/file) the whole book, 3 volumes, PDF, 104 MB. "Цѣдити" is in volume III, page 286 in the book, page 884 in the file.

Comment: a huge thanks to you